# acessing data from another model using remote hooks in loopback

Tags: file-upload, model, updates, cloud9-ide, loopbackjs

I am using loopback in c9 ,basically i have 2 models 
->file(that uploads a file ) 
->user(that has a remote method that updates values fetched from client )
I want to upload the file first and get the uploaded filename as it ll be used by the remote method to be updated in db(monodb).How can I access filename property in file model in user model without model relations. I tried the below code in "user.js"

```
`var loopback=require('loopback');
 var file=loopback.getModel('file');
 console.log(file.name);`
```

but it displays only "undefined".Is it wrong ?if so what's the way to access the filename ??
or should I use hooks?

Answer (score 6):

The upload logic does not seem very clear to me, but if the question is exactly what you ask and is about accessing one model from another model in a remote hook, then you may find the answer here: [Loopback documentation: Getting a reference to a model in JavaScript](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+models#Creatingmodels-GettingareferencetoamodelinJavaScript)

To be more precise, in your user.js you may have something like this:

```
module.exports = function(User) {

    User.beforeRemote('**', function(ctx, unused, next) {
        var File = User.app.models.File;
        ...
    });
}
```